# Perl - Pattern for verbosity levels?

Tags: perl

I have a basic function for printing messages of verbosity levels in a perl package:

```
# 0 = no output, 1 = debug output
our $verbosity = 0;
sub msg {
    (my $verbLevel, my $format, my @addArgs) = @_;
    if ($verbLevel <= $verbosity) {
        printf($format, @addArgs);
    }
}
```

This is IMO an elegant solution inside the package, because to print a debug message I can simply do:

```
msg(1, "Some debug message");
```

However, in practice this package is being 'used' in a long chain of packages, each of which also uses a verbosity feature.  Let's say the chain of usage is like this: entry.pl > package0.pm > package1.pm > package2.pm.  Each file must set the verbosity flag of the next in order for each to work right.

I now think this is an inelegant solution because of duplicate code and the requirement for each "parent file" to set each of it's children's verbosity level.  What I would like to happen is for each *.pm file to inherit the verbosity level and function from entry.pl.

Is there a design pattern I can follow to share a verbosity functionality across packages?  Is there a module out there that can already do this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps look at Log::Log4Perl - either as a model to work from for your own implementation or as a potential replacement.